# Add LogCat in IDEA to any project

Tags: android, cordova, intellij-idea

I work with phonegap project in Intellij IDEA. And sometime I need Android LogCat. But IDEA provides it only if I add android project from platforms folder. But I don't want to add this project because after each build IDEA re-index it.

Comment: If I correctly understood the question, it should help
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476953/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-cordova

Answer (score 0):

You can start the monitor without any other project by running 
{android_sdk_path}/tools/lib/monitor-x86_64/monitor